# Use PDFsharp to import graphics

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp

I am looking at the PDFsharp (PDFsharp-wpf.1.50.5147\lib\net30\PdfSharp-wpf.dll) in the hope that it could be used for importing vector graphics (paths, images, text). The PDFsharp code examples are mostly about creating PDF but there are some parsing and editing capabilities in the library.

```
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfdoc = 
    PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(uri, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
if (pdfdoc == null)
    return;

foreach (PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage pdfpage in pdfdoc.Pages)
{
    PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics graph = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfpage);

    // how to get XGraphicsPath, PathGeometry ?
    // the XGraphicsPathInternals has PathGeometry as WpfPath property 
}
```

Is it possible to enumerate the contents of the XGraphics, convert it to System.Windows.Media.DrawingGroup or similar, that would give me access to graphical primitives in an existing PDF page without need to parse the tokens in page content stream?

I have existing code that handles SVG import via conversion to intermediate DrawingGroup, that might be reusable for PDF if there was a way from PDF page to Drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XGraphics` class allows adding contents to a PDF page, but it does not parse the existing contents of a PDF page.

PDFsharp does not parse the page content stream and extract drawing instructions, so you have to do that with your own code.

Comment: Of course this is an answer and the corrrect one. However it provides no practical advice and does not add any new information because the question itself states the same.

Comment: There is one question in the OP "Is it possible to enumerate the contents of the XGraphics…?" and the answer is "No". I answered the question you asked explicitly, not the question you had in mind. The answer provides information not given in the question, even though it is not the answer you were hoping for. PDFsharp does not parse the page content stream and extract drawing instructions, so you have to do that with your own code.